# How to sort the letters of a string alphabetically?

Tags: c, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *q) {
    char temp, *p;
    int i;

    while(*q) {
        p=q;
        i=1;

        while(*p) {
            if(*p > *(p+i)) {
                temp=*(p+i);
                *(p+i)=*p;
                *p=temp;
            }
            i++;
            p++;
        }
        q++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char str[100]="bonjour";
    function(str);
    printf("%s", str);

    return 0;
}
```

I've been struggling with this code for a while, and I don't know where I am mistaken. I wanted to print a given string in alphabetic order. My program is supposed to swap the previous character with the next one if the the previous character is greater than the next one, but it didn't work at all.

Would you please tell me where did I make a mistake?

Comment: As a stylistic improvement, don't write `*(p+i)`.  Instead, use `p[i]`, which is clearer.  Don't fight the language.

Comment: You increment allways i and p

Comment: Google the C source for "bubble sort" then compare it with what you've got. You could also try single-stepping through your code with your favourite debugger to find the problem.

Comment: @Lundin The Gnome sort is even simpler than Bubble - it has just one `while()` loop instead of two `for()`, and an internal condition to step forth and back, as necessary. And it's N^2, just like Bubble. :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnome_sort

Comment: You need to compare the character at `p` with the next one only, so `i` should always be `1`. Simply get rid of the `i` variable and replace it with constant `1`, just like Amal K shows in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67786627/733637).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `i`. You always have to compare to `p+1` since you have to check the values of 2 adjacent elements. Also, inside the second while loop, use `while(*(p + 1))`, because you only need to compare n-1 times as a single comparison includes two elements.

```
void function(char *q)
{
    char temp, *p;
    while (*q)
    {
        p = q;
        while (*(p + 1))
        {
            if (*p > *(p + 1))
            {
                temp = *(p + 1);
                *(p + 1) = *p;
                *p = temp;
            }
            p++;
        }
        q++;
    }
}
```

```
OUTPUT:
bjnooru
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple bubble sort will do, but its the least efficient sorting algorithm. You can use other sorting algorithms like merge sort or quick sort for much better efficiency, but that's on you.

below is the code using bubble sort :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void function(char *q) {
    
    int len = 0;
    while (q[len] != '\0')  //finds the length of the string(char array);
    {
       len++;
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (q[j] < q[i])    // performs a simple swap
            {
                char temp = q[i];
                q[i] = q[j];
                q[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    char str[100]="bonjour";
    function(str);
    printf("%s", str);//bjnooru

return 0;
}
```

Comment: For (very) few elements, the algorithm efficiency is negligible (or even contradictory).

Comment: for very few elements, absolutely correct, @pmg

Answer (score 0):

more beautiful way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define size 100 
void function(char *q) {
    
    int len = strlen(q);
     //finds the length of the string(char array);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < len; j++)
        {
            if (q[j] < q[i])    // performs a simple swap
            {
                 q[i]=q[i]^q[j]; //use xor
                  q[j] = q[i]^q[j];
                q[i] = q[i]^q[j];
               
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
 char str[size]="bonjour";
  
    function(str);
    printf("%s", str);

return 0;
}
```